# What do I need to do to move my AWS EC2 AMIs from EU to US region?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I want to move my Amazon Web Services AMI from my EU region to the US-east. What steps will i need to do for this.

1. Do I need to create new private key and 509certificate?
2. Do I need to create new security groups
3. Can I move / copy the AMI bundle between regions or do I need to rebundle the machine and upload it to my US S3 bucket?
4. My EU instance is behind a load balancer with cloudwatch monitoring and alarms which trigger autoscaling policies. I assume I will have to redo these in US region too.

Anything else I will need to do?

cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5402013/move-amazon-ec2-amis-between-regions-via-web-interface) and [this one](http://www.dotanmazor.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=96:ec2-ami-move&catid=16:2008-11-14-08-43-34&Itemid=48) answer the first three questions, far too long to repeat in this thread.

4) You have to recreate the load configuration and auto scaling config in the new region, yes.

Answer (score 0):

1) If you want to use the same key-pair, you will have to import it into the target region. (Though the key is not associated until a new instance is launched)

2) Again, if you want to use the same security groups, they must be created in the target region. (and again security groups are not associated until a new instance is launched)

3) In the Spring of 2013, Amazon announced "AMI Copy for Amazon EC2"
Simply, this allows the copy of AMIs between regions.

Documentation for the [AWS Management Console here.](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/CopyingAMIs.html)

[API documentation here.](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/CommandLineReference/ApiReference-cmd-CopyImage.html)

This is the usage for the API command:

```
ec2-copy-image -r source-region -s source-ami-id [-n new-ami-name] [-d new-ami-description] [-c client-token]
```